# Why does F#'s printfn work with literal strings, but not values of type string?

Tags: .net, f#

In the following F# code; I would expect that the `printfn` is being called three times; each with a string. However, the bottom line does not compile (`The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>'`).

What is it about the first two lines that means this can work? Aren't they just strings too?

```
open System

printfn ("\r\n") // Works
printfn ("DANNY") // Works
printfn (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()) // Doesn't compile
```

Comment: I don't get why, since there is `printf` to `print format`, why not a `print` that just prints without formatting? It's easy enough to define as `let print (x : string) = printf "%s" x` but that seems really silly and possibly inefficient.

Comment: There is an approved suggestion to add `print` as an alias of Console.WriteLine. https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1092

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The F# compiler statically analyses the format strings you pass to `printfn` to check that the arguments you pass are valid for the format specifiers you use. For example, the following does not compile:

```
printfn "%d" "some value"
```

since `string` is not compatible with the %d format specifier. The compiler converts valid format strings into a [`TextWriterFormat<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370359.aspx).

It can't do this with arbitrary strings, and since it does not do the conversion, you get the type error above.

You can do the conversion yourself however using `Printf.TextWriterFormat`. 
For example, for a format string requiring a `string` and an `int` you can use:

```
let f = Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> int -> unit>("The length of '%s' is: %d")
printfn f "something" 9
```

Since your string has no format placeholders, you can do:

```
let f = Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
printfn f
```

Comment: Ah; I forgot the compiler was doing magic here; I was thinking about runtime. Makes perfect sense that this only works with strings available at compile time!

Comment: Is the implicit conversion from string to TextWriterFormat<T> something F# does specifically for printf, or can you do this with your own types too?

Comment: "Makes perfect sense that this only works with strings available at compile time!" -- Well, no. `let printsd fmt = Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> int -> unit> fmt |> printfn` works. And if fmt doesn't have the right format specifiers, it fails at runtime.

Comment: @JoeyAdams See http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/07/abusing-printfformat-in-f.html

Answer (score 10):

@Lee's answer is correct as per a possible workaround, but it does not describe what happens with your code.

In an expression `printf "foo"`, the `"foo"` is not a string to be formatted. Instead, it is **input formatter by itself**. More specifically, it is a string literal used to infer the actual type of the `TextWriterFormat<'T>`.

The signature of `printf` is:

```fsharp
printf : TextWriterFormat<'T> -> 'T
```

Since `printfn ("DANNY")` does not contain any format specifiers, the F# compiler infers a `TextWriterFormat<unit>`, and the entire expression becomes `printfn ("DANNY") ()`.

With a variable, it's impossible to statically predict what format specifiers will be there. Consider if `ToLongTimeString()` method was able to return strings of `"%s"` or `"%d %d %d"`, what would be the prototype of the returned function?

When inferring the correct type, a *string literal* works fine, but the variable or `let`-binding does not work:

```fsharp
let foo1 = "foo"
let bar = printf foo // does not compile
[<Literal>] let foo2 = "foo";; // see update below
let bar = printf foo2 // compiles fine
```

In any case, it looks much safer to always use format specifiers:

```fsharp
printf "%s" "DANNY"
printf "%s" (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
```

**Update**: don't forget to type double colon `;;` after `[<Literal>]` value to avoid *warning FS0058* in VS2013.

Comment: Adding literal within let main argv = ... gives Unexpected symbol [< in expression