# Second to last item in a list in F#

Tags: f#

This is what my initial thought was and there were no issues until it was called; What is wrong with this exactly?

```
let SecLastItem myList=  
    List.rev myList
        |>printfn myList.[1]
```

How do I rectify the problem here? What is the best way to find the 2nd to last item of a list?

Comment: The answers here should help you understand your `printfn` problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551851/why-does-fs-printfn-work-with-literal-strings-but-not-values-of-type-string. However, the quick solution is probably `printfn "%s" myList.[1]`, assuming `myList.[1]` is a `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a formatter with `printfn`

```
let SecLastItem myList=  
    let revList = List.rev myList
    printfn "%A" revList.[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

`printfn` expects a format first `printfn "%A" arg`

But there is more, functional programming favors immutability so `List.rev` returns a new list without modifying `mylist`
So printing the second item in myList won't give the second to last just the second from start (if it exists otherwise it'll crash)

That said you should separate function doing something and logging/printing that' better for reuse and composability.

```
// trySecLastItem : 'a list -> 'a option
let trySecLastItem = List.rev >> List.tryItem 2

// usage
printfn "%d" (trySecLastItem someList) // ex Some 42 or None
```

Now as `trySecLastItem` returns an option you have to take care of that (using `defaultArg` for example)

```
// maybeSecLast : int option
let maybeSecLast = trySecLastItem someList
printfn "%d" (defaultArg maybeSecLast 42)
```

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way to find the 2nd to last item of a list?

If you do not want to reverse the list, you can use pattern matching and return an option if the list is not long enough for a 'second to last item'. Something like this.

```
let rec secondToLast ls = 
    match ls with 
    |   []              -> None
    |   h :: ht :: []   -> Some(h)
    |   h :: t          -> secondToLast t
```

test with

```
printfn "%A" (secondToLast [1; 2; 3; 4])
```